# writing linq where or statement

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, where-clause

I am trying to do a search functionality that will check two fields for text containing user input text.

how do I make the following statement work as an OR statement on the `t.TEXT_COMMENT` and `t.TEXT_LANG_DE` fields?

```
translations = translations.Where(t => t.TEXT_FIELD_TYPE.Equals(textType))
                           .Where(t => t.TEXT_COMMENT.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper()))
                           .Where(t => t.TEXT_LANG_DE.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper()))
                           .OrderByDescending(t => t.DATE_MODIFIED).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `||` operator:

```
.Where(t => t.TEXT_COMMENT.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper()) ||
            t.TEXT_LANG_DE.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `||`:

```
translations = translations
   .Where(t => t.TEXT_FIELD_TYPE.Equals(textType))
   .Where(t => t.TEXT_COMMENT.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper())
           ||  t.TEXT_LANG_DE.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearchText.Text.Trim().ToUpper()))
   .OrderByDescending(t => t.DATE_MODIFIED)
   .ToList();
```